# Set specific time in <input type="date"> with Angular

Tags: date, angular, typescript

I would like to set a specific Date programatically for my  control with Angular2, but no matter how I try it, the input always displays "yyyy. mm. dd." in my browser.

Here's my code:
HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" [(ngModel)]="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" min="2016-10-01" [value]="2016-10-01" />
```

Typescript

```
public dateFrom: Date;  
constructor() {
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.dateFrom = new Date(Date.parse("2016-10-01"));
}
```

Please note that min="date" and [value]="date" also didn't work in pure HTML code. Is there something I'm missing or it is a really bad idea, to set an input's value from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the value to be initialized from an Angular2 variable the input has to part of Angular2 form component, a model-driven form or template driven form. And the date input is expecting a string representation of a date, not the javascript date object

> value = date #
>   A string representing a date.

[documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/input.date.html)

Change your code to use string like this:

**TypeScript Component**

```
public dateFrom: string =  "2016-10-01";
```

**Html Component**

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <input type="date"  [(ngModel)]="dateFrom" name="dateFrom"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

this gonna work, see it in action here [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/s5OMg2olU2yHI246nJOG?)

use `date` pipe, `(ngModelChange)` and `[ngModel]`:

```
  <input class="form-control" type="date" [ngModel] ="dateFrom | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="$event = dateFrom" name="dateFrom" min="2016-10-01" [value]="2016-10-01" />
```